# Mysql groups tables with distinct values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following three tables in my database:

bookList:

```
+-----------+-----------------+
| filename  | books           |
+-----------+-----------------+
| fileone   | book1           |
| filetwo   | book1, book3    |
| filethree | book2, book4    |
| filefour  | book1           |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

productList:

```
+-----------+--------------------+
| filename  | products           |
+-----------+--------------------+
| fileone   | product3           |
| filetwo   | product1, product2 |
| filethree | product2, product3 |
| filefour  | product1           |
+-----------+--------------------+
```

compList:

```
+-----------+--------+-------+-------+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| filename  | title  | books1| books2| books3| products1| products2| products3|
+-----------+--------+-------+-------+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| fileone   | title1 | book1 |       |       | product3 |          |          |
| filetwo   | title2 | book3 | book1 |       | product1 | product2 |          |
| filethree | title3 | book4 | book2 |       | product2 |          | product3 |
| filefour  | title4 | book1 |       |       | product1 |          |          |
+-----------+--------+-------+-------+-------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I have used the following code to join the first two tables according to filename:

```
$sql = "SELECT `books`,
    group_concat( DISTINCT `products` ) productList
    FROM bookList b
    JOIN productList p USING (`filename`)
    WHERE b.`books` <> ''
    AND p.`products` <> ''
GROUP BY `books`
";
```

so I get [{book:book1, product:product3}, {book:book2, product:product2, product3}...

I need to query the data so that I get the filename, title and associated products and books. So a desired out put would be

```
[{filname:fileone title:titl1 books:book1 products:product3},
{filename:filetwo title:title2 books:book1,book3 products:product1, product2}.....]
```

Some tips on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you be able and willing to consider a schema redesign? The schema presented is not a good fit for a relational database; it's making your problem harder than it should be.

Comment: I know, but unfortunately for now I have to stick with this. The original table is compList and the 'bookList' and 'productList' are views to break down the table.

Comment: @amar47shah what would you suggest for a schema redesign?

Comment: Just from what I can see so far, I think your desired schema can be summed up like this: "Each file has many books and many products. Each book has one file. Each product has one file." Therefore, I'd suggest three tables: `files`, `books`, and `products`. The `files` table would have a primary key (`id`) and two attributes: `name` and `title`. The `books` and `products` tables would each have a foreign key attribute called `file_id`. For any row in `books` or `products`, the `file_id` attribute value would be the primary key of the `file` that the book or product belongs to.

Comment: @bos570 . . . Edit your question and show the underlying tables.  You probably don't want to use the views for any reasonable query that you would write.

Comment: @GordonLinoff well the main table is compList. I merged the 'book1, book2 and book3' and 'product1, product2, product3' into the the first two tables listed. I couldn't figure out how to use just compList to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So not the  most effective way to do it but I had to create another view with the title and filename as attributes.

I was able to get the desired result with the following mySQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT  * 
FROM titleList AS ts
LEFT  JOIN (

SELECT att.filename, GROUP_CONCAT(  DISTINCT att.products )  AS myProducts
FROM productList AS att
GROUP  BY att.filename
)att ON ts.filename = att.filename
LEFT  JOIN (

SELECT att2.filename, GROUP_CONCAT(  DISTINCT att2.books )  AS myBooks
FROM booksList AS att2
GROUP  BY att2.filename
)att2 ON ts.filename = att2.filename
ORDER  BY ts.filename";
```